# Is there a way to generate a better query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have to map my classes on top of a legacy database.

This is the class diagram
[image]

When I need to get the items to an order EF generates the following query

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Join17].[cd_order_items1] AS [cd_order_items], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN ''1X0X0X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN ''1X0X1X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN ''1X1X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN ''1X2X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN ''1X3X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN ''1X4X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN ''1X5X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN ''1X6X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN ''1X7X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN ''1X8X0X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN ''1X8X1X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN ''1X8X2X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN ''1X9X'' WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN ''1X10X0X'' ELSE ''1X10X1X'' END AS [C1], 
[Join17].[cd_quantity] AS [cd_quantity], 
[Join17].[vl_item] AS [vl_item], 
[Join17].[vl_total] AS [vl_total], 
[Join17].[vl_discount] AS [vl_discount], 
[Join17].[vl_cost_price] AS [vl_cost_price], 
[Join17].[vl_net] AS [vl_net], 
[Join17].[cd_status] AS [cd_status], 
[Join17].[fl_active] AS [fl_active], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[fl_virtual] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[fl_virtual] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) END AS [C2], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_card_type] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_card_type] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS smallint) END AS [C3], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[nr_document] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[nr_document] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C4], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_card] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) END AS [C5], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization1] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization2] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization3] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization4] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization5] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization6] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization7] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization8] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization9] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization10] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization11] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization12] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization13] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[cd_order_customization14] ELSE [Join17].[cd_order_customization15] END AS [C6], 
[Join17].[cd_order] AS [cd_order], 
[Join17].[cd_product] AS [cd_product], 
[Join17].[cd_order_item_base] AS [cd_order_item_base], 
CASE WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[Id1] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''CustomCardOrderItem'') THEN [Join17].[Id2] WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''InterestOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PackageOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''PhotoOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''RechargeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join17].[Discriminator1] = N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) END AS [C7]
FROM  [dbo].[tbl_order_item] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[cd_order_items] AS [cd_order_items1], [Extent2].[cd_quantity] AS [cd_quantity], [Extent2].[vl_item] AS [vl_item], [Extent2].[vl_total] AS [vl_total], [Extent2].[vl_discount] AS [vl_discount], [Extent2].[vl_cost_price] AS [vl_cost_price], [Extent2].[vl_net] AS [vl_net], [Extent2].[cd_status] AS [cd_status], [Extent2].[fl_active] AS [fl_active], [Extent2].[fl_virtual] AS [fl_virtual], [Extent2].[cd_card_type] AS [cd_card_type], [Extent2].[nr_document] AS [nr_document], [Extent2].[cd_card] AS [cd_card], [Extent2].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator1], [Extent2].[cd_order] AS [cd_order], [Extent2].[cd_product] AS [cd_product], [Extent2].[cd_order_item_base] AS [cd_order_item_base], [Extent3].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization1], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent5].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization2], [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent7].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization3], [Extent8].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization4], [Extent9].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization5], [Extent10].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization6], [Extent11].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization7], [Extent12].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization8], [Extent13].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization9], [Extent14].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization10], [Extent15].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization11], [Extent16].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization12], [Extent17].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization13], [Extent18].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization14], [Extent19].[cd_order_customization] AS [cd_order_customization15]
    FROM                  [dbo].[tbl_order_item] AS [Extent2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent3].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[OrderItemShipments] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent4].[OrderItem_Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent5].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent5].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[OrderItemShipments] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent6].[OrderItem_Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent7] ON ([Extent7].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent7].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent8] ON ([Extent8].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent8].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent9] ON ([Extent9].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent9].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent10] ON ([Extent10].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent10].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent11] ON ([Extent11].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent11].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent12] ON ([Extent12].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent12].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent13] ON ([Extent13].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent13].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent14] ON ([Extent14].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent14].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent15] ON ([Extent15].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent15].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent16] ON ([Extent16].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent16].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent17] ON ([Extent17].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent17].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent18] ON ([Extent18].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent18].[cd_order_items])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_order_item_customization] AS [Extent19] ON ([Extent19].[cd_order_items] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[cd_order_items] = [Extent19].[cd_order_items]) ) AS [Join17] ON [Extent1].[cd_order_items] = [Join17].[cd_order_items1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[cd_order_item_base] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[cd_order_item_base] = @EntityKeyValue1) AND ([Join17].[Discriminator1] IN (N''CardOrderItem'',N''CustomCardOrderItem'',N''InterestOrderItem'',N''NotChargedReplacementOrderItem'',N''PackageOrderItem'',N''PhotoOrderItem'',N''RechargeFeeOrderItem'',N''RechargeOrderItem'',N''ReplacementFeeOrderItem'',N''EmailSendPasswordOrderItem'',N''LetterSendPasswordOrderItem'',N''SMSSendPasswordOrderItem'',N''ServiceFeeOrderItem'',N''ExtraShippingOrderItem'',N''RegularShippingOrderItem''))',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=308633
```

Is there anything I can do to generate a better query? If I have a lot of items it is extremely slow

Answer (score 2):

A quick win might be to create a SQL View that joins the tables in a more efficient manner, and then use EF to query the view.

I've used this strategy many times successfully.

Comment: And how I do that, is there a way of EF execute the "view" when the order.Items property is called?

Comment: Thanks not the way it works. First you design an efficient, performant view in your SQL database using CREATE VIEW AS. The view can join together just the right tables you need and it can select just the required columns. Once you've got a working, performant view, then you simply import it in to your EF model and query it as required.